# Windows 10 search bar started displaying unwanted content

Tags: windows-10

Recently my Windows 10 search bar started displaying unwanted content like this one:

[image]

Controlling this kind of behavior is usually a registry key and value. I have tried several with no success.

What is the correct registry key and entry to return it to an empty white box ?

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the appropriate start menu options you have enabled or disabled within Settings. I wasn’t able to reproduce this issue on my Windows 10 system

Comment: Just enabled my Search Bar, and I just see `Type here to search`.

Comment: How do I disable the search bar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be turned on and off by using the 'Show Search Highlights' option found by right clicking on the taskbar and expanding the 'Search ->' submenu:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do it according to [@jack Aidley](https://superuser.com/users/162922/jack-aidley)'s [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1720838/1183289%3C/span%3E).

But like OP said, this can also be done using a registry key.

The key is located at *HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SearchSettings* and you should see “*IsDynamicSearchBoxEnabled*”. If not, right-click or long-press in here and create a new 32-bit DWORD value and name it *IsDynamicSearchBoxEnabled* and for the value, we will set it to 0 to disable, or 1 to enable.

You can run this from the Command Prompt as administrator to disable the feature:

`reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SearchSettings" /v "IsDynamicSearchBoxEnabled" /d 0 /t REG_DWORD /f`

If you change the `/d 0` to `/d 1` it will re-enable it.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/udyw33/search_highlights_new_graphicicon_in_your_search/

Answer (score 1):

This happened because your default search engine is Google and Google does this sort of thing from time to time.

You won't see it if your default engine is left as Bing, you just get the white box.  Equally, wait 24 hours and Google will have gone back to normal.

It isn't a registry settings issue.

Comment: Looks like an option for turning this on and off has now been added, see my answer

Comment: Thanks … if I see a pride flag or BLM logo appear on my desktop, I will lose my mind, then switch to Linux.